# How to not remap array on state change, but only render what is changed?

Tags: reactjs

I have a cart component in my eCommerce app. I want to make animation when product is added or removed from the array. But when the state changes, it completely remaps `CartItem`s from scratch. What is the best way to make what I want (easilly map it first time and only change single components at state change)? Thank you in advance.

```
function Cart() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  return (
    {cart.map(product => (
      <CartItem key={product.id} {...product} />
    ))}
  )
}
```

Comment: Why is mapping everything a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally ok to map all items to their respective react element on every render.
React compares your returned result with what is currently rendered in the DOM and only replaces those elements that changed.
The `key` property is the hint for the framework to know wich items are removed and which items are added.
You can use a package like [react-transition-group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group) which can easily and cleanly do the entering and exiting animations.

Comment: I am sorry. I was using `framer-motion` and thought I set it to animate position, thus I thought it was completely rerendering, but I did not do everything needed. You answer is useful and clarifying tho. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answer said, you just need to make sure to add a `key` property. That way the framework knows if the item has already been mapped.

I had a similar issue trying to render a dropdown, whenever I clicked on the parent it remapped all the children, so the list was becoming infinite at some point. So I just added the `key` property, see example:

```
{dropdownItems.map((item) => (
  item.parent === 'parent' && (
    <Link key={item.id} className={classes.links} to={item.url}>
      <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
        <ListItemText secondary={item.name} />
      </ListItemButton>
    </Link>
  )
))}
```